# WebLogic 11g startup error

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am very new to Oracle WebLogic. I installed WebLogic Server 10.3 using [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/overview/quickstartguidesoasuite11gr1ps4-459545.pdf) on Fedora 14 in development mode. After installation it started up first time successfully. But when I try to start it again, it shows the following error and doesn't do anything. Process is stopped here.

Error is:

```
<Apr 12, 2013 2:41:21 PM IST> <Error> <Coherence> <fedora> <AdminServer> <Logger@9215997 3.7.1.1> <<anonymous>> <> <0000JrxTpjtFw000jzwkno1HPwmR000002> <1365757881226> <BEA-000000> <Oracle Coherence 3.7.1.1 (member=1): Detected soft timeout) of {WrapperGuardable Guard{Daemon=Cluster} Service=ClusterService{Name=Cluster, State=(SERVICE_STARTED, STATE_JOINED), Id=0, Version=3.7.1, OldestMemberId=1}}>
```

I am not able to resolve and my WebLogic server is not starting. Can anybody please tell me why this problem is coming and what will be solution for this.

Comment: Did you look here? https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2355297

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stop all Oracle related services/daemons and then start only weblogic, with a script like 'startWebLogic.cmd' or 'startWebLogic.sh'. Wait some time and try to open the console at the browser, usually at the address [code]http://localhost:7001/console[/code], and, when you see that the weblogic is up and running, start all Oracle related services/daemons again.

The explanation is that Oracle stuff eats all memory and the weblogic finds it difficult to start. Let it start first and the open the gates for Oracle stuff.